# Working with Web Application with an Offline Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Requirement is to run an App in Offline Mode. In case Internet Connection goes down, even then user can access my app. Anybody suggest me how to work with app offline Mode, How my app stores locally on Client's Computer and what we can use for Data Storage etc. And After Communicating with Server, How we can send back all data from offline Mode to Online Mode.  Anybody helps.

Comment: Do you have local server?

Comment: I have no idea how to develop it. Give me some suggestions.

Comment: This is probably completely impossible unless every client has the web application installed locally on their own server, asp.net relies on IIS.

Comment: I also need to store all data on some localDb, and then send back all data from localDB to SqlServer. How we can do it?

Comment: First of all you need to set the database and IIS in local server. Then you can ask everyone to work on that link. And sync your database with live. Then Next step will be, that everyone should be in same network and connected to the local server 24X7. Then final step will be deploying the exact same web application on live server. Now whenever your local server will connect and sync with live database it will get the updated data. And All live users will also get the same updated data.